# Size of a boolean vectorial subspace

Tags: vector-spaces, boolean-algebra

We know that a boolean vectorial space of dimension n is defined by all posible n-tuples formed by 0 or 1 in each position (note this set is finite), and adding to this set the operations of:

- Multiply by an scalar (also 0 or 1) -> Boolean multiplication to all its components by this scalar.
- Add 2 vectors -> Boolean sum component by component.

When we select a set of m independent vectors (note this can be writen as a boolean matrix nxm where m<=n of rank m) we can see it as the basis of a boolean subspace from the main one of dimension n. This vectorial subspace is formed by all possible linear combinations of its basis (note its size is, of course, also finite).

I am interested in getting any kind of relationship among the size of a boolean vectorial subspace and any parameter that define it (dimension, orthogonality of its vectors,...).

My main issue comes from that I am not really familiar with specific tools to be used in finite vectorial spaces.

Comment: Mathematicians denote $\{0,1\}$ as $F=GF(2)$ (Galois Field with two elements) and you are working with the cartesian product $F^n$ which is a vector space over $F$. These notations will help you to have access to a vast litterature. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34042. Are you accustomed with the very precise meaning of the word "field" in algebra ?

Comment: Thanks for this, really appreciated. I will try right now.

Comment: @JeanMarie: That was what I thought, too, but the OP doesn't seem to be talking about a vector space over a field at all. For instance, in a BVS, we would have $v+v=v$ for all vectors $v,$ whereas in a vector space over $GF(2),$ we instead have $v+v=0$ for all vectors $v.$

Comment: I think the issue is that you  have to choose between addition $1+1=0$ (which is a "xor" addition) which is the framework permitting to speak about vector subspaces, etc... or the addition rule $1+1=1$ which is much "closed on itself" (I wrote at first "algebraicaly poor") without rich algebraic structures... Abandon in this case subspaces and the like...

Comment: @CameronBuie is right I am not using GF(2) as it uses AND and XOR as product and sum rules, but usual boolean algebra rules AND and OR.

Comment: @Cameron Blue I send the last comment without having seen yours. Happy that we see it in the same way...

Comment: Boolean algebra uses more and more alternatives to connectives "or" and "and" (and "not") ; the most important one is to express all expressions with "xor" (exclusive or) and keep "and" (and "not"). This allows to express many more concepts because you have in this way the powerful algebraic machinery of the Galois **Field** $GF(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for all explanation but I am still focused in {0,1} and AND, OR operations to define my vectorial spaces.

Comment: A question I have been recently answering which shows the interest of working with "xor" ($1 \oplus 1 = 0$ : note the special symbol to distinguish it from ordinary boolean $+$)  : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3027931

Comment: Do you know the following document : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/eb75/42d6a5291c10ecad6965cc9438256b3753b5.pdf ?

Comment: Yes, I knew from It. Thanks anyway.